# Select options are getting separated from select box when the div above it is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a validation message under a input. When a user inputs a message in the input and then selects an option from the select box the validation message hides and the select options get separated from the select box. I'm looking for a way to keep the options directly under the select box.

Thanks in advance.

Here is some quick code.

```
<input type='text' id='message'/>    
<div id='msg'>add your message</div>
<select name="schools" id="schools" value="School" title="School">
    <option value="">School</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

$('#message').blur(function () {
    $('#msg').fadeOut();
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5qbEM/29/.

Looks like this is a chrome bug.

Comment: Works for me in the same fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5qbEM/29/

Comment: That's exactly what I said att first, but if you type in the box and then change it....

Comment: Just realized this is only happening in Google Chrome.

Comment: @user973671 I'm in firefox and it happened for me too